# Custom animation for navwindows Titanium

Tags: animation, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

```
//load up profile controller.
function go_to_profile() {
    var controller = Alloy.createController('Profile', {
        title : 'Profile',
        name : '_profile',
        isFlyout : true
    });
    var newWindow = controller.getView();
    Alloy.Globals.navGroup.openWindow(newWindow, {
        animated : true,
        transition:Titanium.UI.iPhone.AnimationStyle.CURL_UP
    });

}
```

Here is my code. I would like to modify it, so that the window slides in upwards. The transition does not seem to work and keeps sliding in from left to right.

Any idea why, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, the `Ti.UI.iOS.NavigationWindow` doesn't allow the transitions.

Only when you call `Window.open()' you can define a transition prop.

Comment: Is there anyway I can change my code so that this is possible? I am using nav windows

Comment: Create two `NavigationWindow`, and use its as a Windows.
But this has no sense.